# Rails 4: Params not passed back to view after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a basic form for creating a project...

```
<%= form_for(@project, :url => {:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field(:name, {class: "form-control"}) %>
<%= f.text_area(:instructions, {class: "form-control"}) %>
<%= f.submit('Create Project') %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, I have two actions:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.new( project_params )
    if @project.save
        flash[:notice]= "New project created!"
        redirect_to(:action=>'index')
    else
      flash[:error]="Problem creating project"
      redirect_to(:action=>'new')
    end
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new()
  end
```

I have a couple validations which prevent the fields from being empty. When the form fails, I get redirected back to the "new" page again, but the `@project` variable is always empty.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to redirect on an error, you want to render: doing so means the `new` page will be rendered with variables from (and the URL of) the `create` action, pre-populating your form fields as you would expect.

Change your controller action to this:

```
def create
    @project = Project.new( project_params )
    if @project.save
        flash[:notice]= "New project created!"
        redirect_to(:action=>'index')
    else
      flash[:error]="Problem creating project"
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `redirect_to(:action=>'new')` to `render 'new'`